# Arch/OSX - fstab options for shared /home (HFS+) on SSD

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab, ssd, hfs+

I've got an Arch and OS X install sharing an HFS+ (non-journaled) /home partition. My Arch side seems to have issues with the partition. In particular, deleting multiple files causes the drive to crash (not sure if it gets unmounted, but ranger and other applications can't see it anymore and shutting down then causes a kernel panic). My fstab entry is:

`/dev/sda4     /home     hfsplus     defaults 0 0`

I tried using

`/dev/sda4     /home     hfsplus     rw,relatime,nls=utf8 0 0`

and it seems to be working pretty well, but I don't understand ftsab enough to know if this is going to be a permanent solution.

I've got `rootflags=data=writeback` in my kernel options.

Anyone know what the proper options would be for mounting /home with a non-journaled hfsplus partition on an ssd?